# Recreating Dynamic iOS Wallpaper in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

Forgive the abstract nature of this question, but I am working on a project to replicate the Dynamic Wallpaper that comes included with iOS.  In effect, I am working to accomplish what is seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWIGr.jpg), a set of circles that appear on-screen in random positions and float around randomly.

I am creating my circles as a subclassed UIView, as seen here:

```
class BokehCircle: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // Set the path
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)

        // Set the fill color
        UIColor.purple.setFill()

        // Fill
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Then, I am adding my circles to my view at random points (code omitted for length, but this is functioning properly).

Where I am struggling now is to determine how to make the circles "float" about the screen, slowly, randomly, but never fully disappear off-screen.  While I know how to animate positions using a CGAffineTransform, I'm hoping for some *suggestions* (you don't need to do my work for me) on where to turn.  Using the term "float" is resulting in very skewed results and I'm not finding any help on what would accomplish this effect.

Comment: Use emit layer?

Comment: Thanks, @E.Coms, I was researching this (and SceneKit Particles, though it's a little above my head).  What I struggled with was determining whether these "particles" or "cells" could already exist on-screen, in various positions, rather than being "emitted" from a certain point.  I need them all over, not just emitting from one point.

Comment: I mean CAEmitterLayer.

Comment: Thanks @E.Coms, I follow.  I'm working with it now.  I'm trying to determine how to better change the size of my CAEmitterCell and also how to make the emit point more random than just one specific point.

Comment: If you use Xcode, you have tools when you build a SpriteKit particle system. CAemitlayer and particle system are quite similar. One is for CA animation. The other is for 2D animation.

Comment: @E.Coms Understood.  What I'm struggling with, like in the Dynamic Wallpapers example, is that the SpriteKit Particle System/CAEmitterLayer all originate from one point.  I need my particles to come from a variety of points.  I also need them to exist on screen and float indefinitely, not "die" and then regenerate.  I've yet to figure out what settings would allow that.

Comment: Yes, it takes time. But I am sure it's there. You can set emitterLayer.emitterShape= kCAEmitterLayerRectangle and emitterLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(x: 100, y:200)  for a range. set cell.lifetime = Float. infinity. They will never "dir"

Comment: Thank you.  The Float.infinity was helpful.  I'm still struggling to figure out how many "cells" to emit at one time (I.E. I have birthRate set to 1, but I'm still getting multiple cells on screen at one time, whereas I'd only like one at a time)

Comment: There are two birthrate. one is cells and the other is the layer.birthrate. They multiply to get final numbers

Comment: Why are there so many of them?!  lol.  I have cell birthrate and layer birthrate set to one, but I'd like one item on screen (for the sake of testing).  Yet with both birthrates set to one, there are still five or six particles being emitted.

Comment: It's random. You cannot control one I think. You may need to add layer later. etc. But layers are very flexible. one layer can add multiple cells. Each cells actually can add more cells

Comment: I see.  So there's no way to do a CAEmitterLayer that only emits ONE particle, for infinity?  I could then do several CAEmitterLayers if I could get that to work.